# Scala - Enforcing size of Vector at compile time

Tags: scala, tuples, compile-time, type-systems

Is it possible to enforce the size of a `Vector` passed in to a method at compile time? I want to model an n-dimensional Euclidean space using a collection of points in the space that looks something like this (this is what I have now):

```
case class EuclideanPoint(coordinates: Vector[Double]) {
  def distanceTo(desination: EuclieanPoint): Double = ???
}
```

If I have a coordinate that is created via `EuclideanPoint(Vector(1, 0, 0))`, it is a 3D Euclidean point. Given that, I want to make sure the destination point passed in a call to `distanceTo` is of the same dimension.

I know I can do this by using `Tuple1` to `Tuple22`, but I want to represent many different geometric spaces and I would be writing 22 classes for each space if I did it with `Tuple`s - is there a better way?

Comment: I can't in good conscious make this an _answer_, but it might qualify as an idea... The first thing that occurred to me is to combine a Value Class (new in 2.10) with path-dependent types to get a type that represents s specific integer. I have no real idea whether this could be made to work. I might give it a try when work is over for the day... See SIP 15: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

Comment: This kind of constraint can be encoded with "type-level programming". See, for example, the [Apocalisp blog series](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/), and in particular HList.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to do this in a number of ways that all look more or less like what Randall Schulz has described in a comment. The [Shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) provides a particularly convenient implementation, which lets you get something pretty close to what you want like this:

```
import shapeless._

case class EuclideanPoint[N <: Nat](
   coordinates: Sized[IndexedSeq[Double], N] { type A = Double }
) {
  def distanceTo(destination: EuclideanPoint[N]): Double = 
    math.sqrt(
      (this.coordinates zip destination.coordinates).map {
        case (a, b) => (a - b) * (a - b)
      }.sum
    )
}
```

Now you can write the following:

```
val orig2d = EuclideanPoint(Sized(0.0, 0.0))
val unit2d = EuclideanPoint(Sized(1.0, 1.0))

val orig3d = EuclideanPoint(Sized(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
val unit3d = EuclideanPoint(Sized(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
```

And:

```
scala> orig2d distanceTo unit2d
res0: Double = 1.4142135623730951

scala> orig3d distanceTo unit3d
res1: Double = 1.7320508075688772
```

But not:

```
scala> orig2d distanceTo unit3d
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : EuclideanPoint[shapeless.Nat._3]
 required: EuclideanPoint[shapeless.Nat._2]
              orig2d distanceTo unit3d
                                ^
```

`Sized` comes with a number of nice features, including a handful of collections operations that carry along static guarantees about length. We can write the following for example:

```
val somewhere = EuclideanPoint(Sized(0.0) ++ Sized(1.0, 0.0))
```

And have an ordinary old point in three-dimensional space.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! Quick question - is it possible to turn an `IndexedSeq[Double]` into the `Sized` version? I'm digging through the code and am having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Question: Does Shapeless require the pre-release / snapshot / nascent Scala 2.11? 'Cause when I retrieved it and built it, it used a 2.11 snapshot Scala. (Also, it doesn't compile, but I'm uncertain what that's about...)

Comment: No, you can get version 1.2.3 of Shapeless for 2.10.0 (or 2.9.2), either via an SBT or Maven dependency, or by checking out the `shapeless-1.2.3` tag and building that.

Comment: @adelbertc: You can with `Sized.wrap`, but note that you'll have to specify the length at the type level, and it's then your responsibility to make sure that's correct—if it's not, all the guarantees you get from that point on are pretty much worthless.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something your self by doing a type level encoding of the Natural Numbers like: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/. Then just parametrizing your Vector by a Natural. Would not require the extra dependency, but would probably be more complicated then using Shapeless.